# Set a formula in an Excel Cell composed by a string and a integer using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am getting an error on VBA when doing the following:

```
filterTotalRow = orderCount + 5
Cells(138, 5).Value = "=SUBTOTAL(3;E3:E" + filterTotalRow + ")"
```

But I get an error. 
What is wrong?
How can I insert a formula composed by a string and a number, as described?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong symbol for concatenation. You should use '&' instead of '+'

```
Cells(138, 5).Value = "=SUBTOTAL(3;E3:E" & filterTotalRow & ")"
```

Comment: Still not working... I am getting the error 1004 now.

Comment: I also had to substitute the ";" by , - as VBA is english centric.